# Mysterious Error: The specified type member 'tagdata' is not supported in LINQ to Entities

Tags: asp.net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

In my ASP .NET MVC 4(VS 2012) with MySQL db , I am using database first approach through entity framework. I SUCESSFULLY added  two new tables in my database manually. So now i can use these two tables and everything is working fine related to these two tables. I can insert data in them, show them, perform logical operation on them. But because of these changes some of my api links are not working, giving this error :

> The specified type member 'tagdata' is not supported in LINQ to
>   Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation
>   properties are supported.

StackTrace:

> " at
>   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MemberAccessTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter
>   parent, MemberExpression linq) at
>   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter
>   parent, Expression linq) at
>   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression
>   linq) at
>   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.ThenByTranslatorBase.Translate(ExpressionConverter
>   parent, MethodCallExpression call) at
>   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter
>   parent, MethodCallExpression call, SequenceMethod sequenceMethod) at
>   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter
>   parent, MethodCallExpression linq) at
>   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter
>   parent, Expression linq) at
>   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression
>   linq) at
>   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.ThenByTranslatorBase.Translate(ExpressionConverter
>   parent, MethodCallExpression call) at
>   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter
>   parent, MethodCallExpression call, SequenceMethod sequenceMethod) at
>   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter
>   parent, MethodCallExpression linq) at
>   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter
>   parent, Expression linq) at
>   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression
>   linq) at
>   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.ThenByTranslatorBase.Translate(ExpressionConverter
>   parent, MethodCallExpression call) at
>   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter
>   parent, MethodCallExpression call, SequenceMethod sequenceMethod) at
>   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter
>   parent, MethodCallExpression linq) at
>   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter
>   parent, Expression linq) at
>   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression
>   linq) at
>   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.UnarySequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter
>   parent, MethodCallExpression call) at
>   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter
>   parent, MethodCallExpression call, SequenceMethod sequenceMethod) at
>   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter
>   parent, MethodCallExpression linq) at
>   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter
>   parent, Expression linq) at
>   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression
>   linq) at
>   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.UnarySequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter
>   parent, MethodCallExpression call) at
>   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter
>   parent, MethodCallExpression call, SequenceMethod sequenceMethod) at
>   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter
>   parent, MethodCallExpression linq) at
>   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter
>   parent, Expression linq) at
>   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression
>   linq) at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.Convert() at
>   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1
>   forMergeOption) at
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1
>   forMergeOption) at
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalQuery`1.GetEnumerator() at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
>   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source) at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonArrayContract.CreateWrapper(Object
>   list) at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter
>   writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member,
>   JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty
>   containerProperty) at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter
>   jsonWriter, Object value) at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter
>   jsonWriter, Object value) at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object
>   value) at
>   System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter.<>c_*DisplayClassd.b*_c()
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpers.RunSynchronously(Action action,
>   CancellationToken token)" }

**Sorry i forgot to mention that there is nothing wrong with the linq queries i am using within my controllers, because :
1) Even if i comment out all those controllers that are using these two new tables, still i am getting the same error. 
2) Those linq queries are doing what they are supposed to do.**

Error is occusing when i am trying to access un related controllers. What could have gone possibly wrong? This started happening?

Comment: i'm sure many will ask as well... you need to add the relevant class code, rather than a huge copy paste of the eror. without context ANYTHING could be the issue. take 5 more mins on the question and you'll be rewarded with a shining answer -that's SO for you.

Comment: could you show your linq/lambda code please

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention that there is nothing wrong with the linq queries i am using within my controllers, because even if i comment out all those controllers that are using these new two tables, still i am getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably a data type mismatch ...For example "xml" data is not recognized in edmx...May be something similar...

Comment: I think you have reached there. But datatype for what?

Comment: You need to give details of the table structure you are querying and the relevant .net code ...otherwise it is impossible for anyone to answer the question.

Comment: what do you mean by un related controllers? With using linq ,how can you access tables in your controller?

Comment: the newly added tables were tags and tagdata. From unrelated controllers i mean, user controller, message controller, like where i am not even quering these two tables. I am using Web API so i am querying the tables from linq.

Comment: If I got your question correctly it is the result after updating edmx with 2 new tables ...u have two options to resolve this..a) Delete all the tables in edmx files and create freshly .b) after updating edmx you have to open " .tt" files in the edmx project and click on save. It should work for you

Comment: You are right that would be easy. I could have right clicked on emdx file and select "Update Modal from Database", but unfortunately i cant because i have some problem with my mysql connector i am using.

So I  have to manually add two tables in edmx xml file, dbcontext and classes for that table

Comment: Do one thing...assuming you are not changing the db schema ,just delete the edmx project and create it once again. That's the only solution I could think of as I have not worked in MySQL.